# Errors compiling a DLL in Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have to create a dll with a function in C++. I created the project by choosing DLL and I used the default sample example created automatically in the beginning.

I edited 2 files :

**OCR2.h**

```
using namespace std;


#ifdef OCR2_EXPORTS
#define OCR2_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define OCR2_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Cette classe est exportée de OCR2.dll
class OCR2_API COCR2 {
public:
    COCR2(void);
    // TODO: ajoutez ici vos méthodes.
};

extern OCR2_API int nOCR2;

OCR2_API int fnOCR2(void);
OCR2_API bool comparer(bool latin, string lienInitial, string lienStr1, string lienStr2, string lienStr3);
```

And my **OCR2.cpp**

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
// Il s'agit d'un exemple de variable exportée
OCR2_API int nOCR2=0;

// Il s'agit d'un exemple de fonction exportée.
OCR2_API int fnOCR2(void)
{
    return 42;
}


OCR2_API bool comparer(bool latin, string lienInitial, string lienStr1, string lienStr2, string lienStr3)
{
// my function
}

COCR2::COCR2()
{
    return;
}
```

While building the project, I have the error C2061 in Visual studio 2015 with the description :

> "erreur de syntaxe : identificateur 'string'"

Which means "syntax error : identifiable 'string'.

I want to know if the way I used to create the DLL is correct, if yes, why do I have this error while building?

Thank  you

Comment: Add `#include "ocr2.h"` to the list of #includes.

Comment: `OCR2.cpp` doesn't include `OCR2.h`. The header doesn't include `std::string`. `using namespace std;` is bad practice.